# Clone a git-svn repo by getting all of the svn part from the original svn repo

Tags: linux, git, git-svn, clone, fetch

How can I clone a git repo from my laptop (at home) to a server (at university) while getting most of the repo from a third (svn) repo at another uni that is the main codebase.  I'd like to minimise the amount of home<->uni traffic by maximising uniOne<->uniTwo traffic.

this is what I have now on Laptop:

```
--o--o--o---o---o---o git-svn trunk  
         `--o--o-o--o git mybranch
```

this is what I would like to get on uniOne:

```
--o--o--o---o---o---o git-svn trunk <-- from uniTwo  
         `--o--o-o--o git mybranch  <-- from Laptop
```

After cloning the repo should be able to pull branches from Laptop.

I have tried: on uniOne: git-svn clone uniTwo, git remote add Laptop, but then git fetch wants to get the whole thing from Laptop.  I thought maybe using git clone --depth x Laptop and then graft them together might work but it still requires all of the source files to be transfered Laptop->uniOne, not just the changes.  I could try to export all patches from Laptop and apply them on top of a fresh svn checkout then get it to track the branch on my Laptop (if that is possible) but it would be easier to wait until I am next at uni and then just clone normally.

Comment: Your uniOne/uniTwo description is slightly confusing. Could you perhaps update and clarify? This is my understanding so far:

There is a Subversion repository at your University that you have to interact with. You want to clone a project inside this SVN repository into a Git repository that you can bring home on your laptop, right?

Comment: There are two unis: one with the svn repo (uniTwo), the other where I have access to big-computer time (uniOne).  I develop simulations on my laptop and run them on uniOne.  The crux is that upload speeds from my laptop at home are very slow and all three computers are far apart.  On uniOne, I'd like to be able to pull from laptop but wherever possible get from the svn repo at uniTwo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define your repositories:

- **git-svn** <-- this is the Subversion repository at University
- **uni/master** <-- this is a Git repository at your University. This is jus a "fetching repository" that gets the latest history from the Subversion repo.
- **laptop/master** <-- This is the Git repository on your laptop. This is where you work.

I would suggest the following setup:

Create **uni/master** by doing `git svn clone` of **git-svn**. 
Automatically or regularly update **uni/master** with the latest changes from **git-svn** by running `git svn rebase` (trigger with a commit hook, cron-job, or manually every time you're at Uni).

Create **laptop/master** by cloning **uni/master**. Here you can commit locally as often as you want. When you are at University, get the latest changes from **uni/master** by running `git pull --rebase` (you always have to do --rebase to keep history linear, because SVN won't understand git-branches).

When you want to push changes from your laptop back to **git-svn**, you have to configure the git-svn remote on your **laptop/master** first:

```
git svn init https://url.to.uni-svn-repo
```

Now you can push your latest changes back to **uni-svn** with `git svn dcommit`. Note that you might have to update the reference to the latest commit in **uni/master** first. first:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/uni/master
```

DO NOT attempt to push from your **laptop/master** to **uni/master**. This will only bring chaos as the rebasing/rewriting history will just confuse Git when it tries to sync with **git-svn** again.

See also http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion where I've started collecting up a bunch of tips for working with Git and SVN together.